# Accesing Stylistic Sets with unicode-math

Tags: unicode-math

Consider the following MnWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{MinionPro-It}[range={scr,bfscr,cal,bfcal},StylisticSet={1}]

\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{equation}%
\mathscr{AB} = \mathcal{AB}AB
\end{equation}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

While the output is set in Minion Pro, the swashes are not used. This worked until recently. I have an up-to-date MikTex. Is there a possibility to access the swashes?

Answer (score 1):

For some reason I don't quite understand it works with `Contextuals=Swash` (but not with `Style=Swash` (?)).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{MinionPro-It}[range={scr,bfscr,cal,bfcal},Contextuals=Swash]
\begin{document}
$\mathscr{AB} = \mathcal{AB}AB$
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: From memory those are two different opentype features, so it makes sense that only one of them works.

Comment: @WillRobertson It is weird that it is the `Contextuals` option (`+cswh`) instead of the `Style` option (`+swsh`), as the contextuals should apply to, for example, the first letter of a word, whereas the style should replace all letters by swashes.